# Cannot see products on homepage

Tags: magento2, product, widget, create-product

I did the following:

1. Logged into Admin
2. Created a `simple product`
3. Added a `product list widget` to the home page
4. Reloaded cache

... And I cannot see my product displayed on the homepage.

Comment: Please share the widget rule and check if the product is saleable.

Comment: @AnshuMishra it seems to be working now.